# Rails: Hide record with button, can not find record with id error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I am implementing a method to hide records from a table but not delete from my database via a button. I added a column "revision_active" boolean attribute to my table which is set to false. With a view condition records can be shown that are only set to true.

My button(to set attributes to true via checkboxes):

```
<%= form_tag update_multiple_homeworks_path(:revision_active => true), method: :put do %>
....
<td><%= check_box_tag "homework[id][]", homework.id, checked = false %></td>
....

<%= submit_tag "Add to Bucket", :remote => true, :class => 'smallMobileRight button text-left' %>
```

In my routes:

```
resources :homeworks do
    collection do
    put 'update_multiple'
 end
end
```

In my controller:

```
def update_multiple
        if params[:homework][:id]
            @homework_ids = params[:homework][:id]
            @homework_ids.each do |id|
                Homework.revision_active = true
            end
        else 
    redirect_to homeworks_homework_details_path  
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        flash[:notice] = "Added to your Bucket!"
        format.html { redirect_to homeworks_homework_details_path }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js { render :layout => false }
    end
  end
```

Params

```
...
"_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"blah",
 "homework"=>{"id"=>["107"]},
 "commit"=>"Add to Bucket",
 "revision_active"=>"true",
 "id"=>"update_multiple"}
```

Error upon button click:

```
Couldn't find Homework with 'id'=update_multiple
```

Any ideas? I'm not catching an array of ids, error in controller? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I am not going to give the exact answer because this is a very specific question and doesn't seem to be very beneficial to other people. I figured it's better for you to read into documentation to learn how to do that. So I will point you to some resources instead.

**Your route**

Looks like you are passing in `update_multiple` as an id, and your route helper takes an id as an argument.

Since this is updating a collection, you shouldn't be doing operation on a specific record.

You can run `rake routes` to find out what parameter it takes after you construct the route. (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

**Your checkbox**

```
<%= check_box_tag "homework[id][]", homework.id, checked = false %>
```

should be as below.

```
<%= check_box_tag "homework_ids[]", homework.id, checked = false %>
```

Refer to here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag

**In your controller**

What you want might be this `params[:homework_ids]`

Refer to here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters